# beginner javascript; for loop with array of objects coming out as undefined

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, constructor

Here is my code

```
function Person (name, age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}

var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);

for (i =0; i<= family.length; i++) {
    console.log (family[i].name);
}
```

This produces an error:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Can anyone point me in the right direction from here?

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating one too far.

```
for (var i = 0; i < family.length; i++)
```

JavaScript arrays start at zero, and the last non-empty cell is at `length - 1`. Thus you have to stop iterating when your index is equal to the length, not when it's greater than the length.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your test condition to `i < family.length`, you're getting out of bounds.

Comment: Welcome. If it solved your problem, you can mark it as an answer also.

Answer (score 1):

What about `i < family.length`?

Answer (score 1):

Change <= to <. You are exceeding the array limit.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine.

```
for (i =0; i<= family.length; i++)
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/285Th/1/